# ios get storyboard name in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have 2 view connect same class but view's storyboard names different can i get storyboard name ?[image]

Like that same view connect same class `ViewControllerMain` 1st view storyboard name : firstScreen 2nd view storyboard name :secontScreen

How can i understand in viewDidLoad screen in which I am. This is possible ?

Comment: why dont you use one story board with different UIViewcontrollers ?

Comment: view almost do same thing only exist small differences i do not want to create new class

Comment: Do you have 1 storyboard or 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the identity inspector of IB there's a `Restoration ID` field you can fill with a string of your choice. Once set, you can retrieve it using:

```
self.restorationIdentifier
```

Just choose 2 different strings for the 2 VC and you're done, you can check the actual value at runtime.

**Addendum**: This method also works if the 2 view controllers are in the same storyboard.